# How can I break line after specific scheme in text

Tags: javascript, textarea, chess

I am writing an a chess player and I have this script in js file that writes [PGN](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) to the text area.

Instead of this:

[image: img n21]

My script does this:

[image]

I am using [chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js) for the backend and code that prints out the PGN in the function that is called every piece drop, so it updates every time player does a move.

#### Javascript

```js
var updateEveryMove = function(){
  document.getElementById('pgnview').innerHTML = chess.pgn();
};
```

#### HTML

```html
<textarea readonly id="pgnview" class="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

What script will I have to do in order to PGN was printed like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLV3X.png) picture.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `chess.pgn();` returns?

Comment: Depending on the game. It returns game's Protable Game Notation. In this case only moves. Every move it is updated. You can see it on the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As their documentation says [here](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js#pgn-options-), you can pass options such as `newline_char` in `chess.pgn()` to decide what to add before every new line. You can pass `\n` which adds a new line in the `<textarea>` to show moves in a new line.

```
var updateEveryMove = function(){
  document.getElementById('pgnview').innerHTML = chess.pgn({newline_char: '\n'});
};
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, although I had to do `document.getElementById('pgnview').innerHTML = chess.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '\n'});` and it worked. Thanks for help!